# How can I make sure that a certain line is printed only when the if statement is met in a while-loop

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to print an if statement but only if the values are correct and they meet the requirements. However, the if statement is inside of a while loop and even though it asks the user to try again when the value in the if statement is not correct it still prints out the numbers the user inputted the first time in the WriteLine outside of the if statement (where it says SIMULATION). I want it to ask the user to try again until the values meet the required standard of the if statement.

```cs
namespace Woodchuck
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string restart = "Y";


            while (restart == "Y")
            {
                int totalWoodChucks = 0;
                int days = 0;

                const int MAXDAYS = 10;
                const int MINDAYS = 1;
                const int MAXWOOD = 100;
                const int MINWOOD = 1;


                Write("Enter number of woodchucks for this simulation (1-100): ");
                int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out totalWoodChucks);

                if (totalWoodChucks > MAXWOOD || totalWoodChucks < MINWOOD)
                {
                    WriteLine("Please try again");
                }


                Write("Enter number of days for this simulation (1-10): ");
                int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out days);
                if (days > MAXDAYS || days < MINDAYS)
                {
                    WriteLine("Please try again");
                }


                WriteLine($"SIMULATION 1: {totalWoodChucks} woodchucks over {days} days");

                Write("\nTo run another simulation, enter 'Y':");
                restart = ReadLine().ToUpper();

            }
            //Debug pause
            WriteLine("Press any key to wrap it up...");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a while loop until the required conditions are met.

Here is a simple example of how you could do this:

```
int totalWoodChucks = 0;
int days = 0;

const int MAXDAYS = 10;
const int MINDAYS = 1;
const int MAXWOOD = 100;
const int MINWOOD = 1;

bool validWoodChucks = false;
while(!validWoodChucks)
{
    Console.Write("Enter number of woodchucks for this simulation (1-100): ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out totalWoodChucks);

    if(totalWoodChucks > MAXWOOD || totalWoodChucks < MINWOOD)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid woodchucks. Please try again.");
    }
    else
    {
        validWoodChucks = true;
    }

}

bool validDays = false;
while(!validDays)
{
    Console.Write("Enter number of days for this simulation (1-10): ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out days);
    if (days > MAXDAYS || days < MINDAYS)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid days. Please try again.");
    }
    else
    {
        validDays = true;
    }
}


Console.WriteLine("Wood chucks: " + totalWoodChucks);
Console.WriteLine("Days: " + days);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Example when used:

```
Enter number of woodchucks for this simulation (1-100): -10
Invalid woodchucks. Please try again.
Enter number of woodchucks for this simulation (1-100): 50
Enter number of days for this simulation (1-10): 20
Invalid days. Please try again.
Enter number of days for this simulation (1-10): 10
Wood chucks: 50
Days: 10
```

Answer (score -1):

string restart = "Y";

```
    while(restart == "Y")
    {
        int totalWoodChucks = 0;
        int days = 0;

        const int MAXDAYS = 10;
        const int MINDAYS = 1;
        const int MAXWOOD = 100;
        const int MINWOOD = 1;


        Write("Enter number of woodchucks for this simulation (1-100): ");
        int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out totalWoodChucks);
        Write("Enter number of days for this simulation (1-10): ");
        int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out days);

        if((totalWoodChucks > MAXWOOD || totalWoodChucks < MINWOOD) &&(days > MAXDAYS || days < MINDAYS))
        {
            WriteLine("Please try again");
            continue;
        }

        WriteLine($"SIMULATION 1: {totalWoodChucks} woodchucks over {days} days");

        Write("\nTo run another simulation, enter 'Y':"); 
        restart = ReadLine().ToUpper();

    }
    //Debug pause
    WriteLine("Press any key to wrap it up...");
```

What I did was make the checking after the all data is been gathered. then if the data does not meet the requirements it will ask again for another try until the data has been satisfied.